# Removing "Go" Button from the SoftKeyboard in a Web App using jQueryMobile

Tags: android, ios, iphone, android-softkeyboard, jquery-mobile-button

Im working on a Web App using jQueryMobile. Application is similar to a chat functionality. I want the user to use the "Send" button on the screen and not to use the "Go" button on the soft keyboard. I can disable the form submit but I want to remove the "Go" button completely like the Android SMS App does..Is it possible to manipulate the Softkeyboard layout from a Mobile Web App ?

Thanks,
-Sreeni

Comment: Its not even possible to manipulate it from Java.  The way to do this in Java is to set the imeAction on the field.  This will tell the keyboard that the field wants to use a send button, and the keyboard will then sometimes honor it (depending on other settings and the keyboard itself).  For a web app, the only thing you can really do is fiddle with the field type I believe.